# how to fix browscap.ini error on my web server

Tags: php, browser-detection, browscap

I use php to build my web page which i upload to my web server. On visit my page this error message display on my webpage that is on my web server but does not display on my wamp serve(my localhost) it work well.

```
Cannot open '/home2/codeplac/public_html/browscap.ini' for reading
```

how can i fix this issue and what exactly do I need to do on my web server thanks

Comment: looks like your `browscap.ini` resource doesn't exist at that path on the server.  Post the corresponding html or php that references that file

Comment: so in this directory '/home2/codeplac/public_html/ on my web server you are saying i should upload browscap.ini to my serve. if so how can I get it the one that works for php web pages

Answer (score 2):

It is a file that allows you to better recognize which browser is used by the client.
Download from the project website: https://browscap.org

I downloaded the PHP versions, copied them to the directory and renamed the link in php.ini because the downloaded file had a name extension.

After restarting Apache the error message was gone.

---

I have specified the complete path, incl. drive.